# Is reflection actually useful apart from reverse engineering?

Tags: reflection

Languages such as Java and PHP support reflection, which allows objects to provide metadata about themselves. Are there any legitimate use cases where you would need to be able to do something like ask an object what methods it has outside of the realm of reverse engineering? Are any of those use cases actually implemented today?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is reflection, and why is it useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)

Comment: ...which was just the first of the 'Related' questions that SO automatically listed. I find it hard to believe that *nothing* useful was auto-suggested to you as you composed this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There certainly are good use cases. For example, obtaining developer-provided metadata. Java APIs are increasingly using annotations to provide info about methods/fields/classes and their use. Like input validation, binding to data representations... You could use these at compile-time to generate metadata descriptors and use those, but to do it at runtime would require reflection. Even if you used the metadata descriptors, they'd end up containing things like class, method and field names that'd need to be accessed via reflection.

Another use case: dynamic languages. Take Ruby... It allows you to check up-front whether an object would respond to a method name before trying to call that method. Something like that requires reflection.

Or how about when a class or method name must be provided from outside compiled code, like when selecting an implementation of some API. That's just gonna be a bit of text. Looking up what it resolves to comes down to reflection.

Answer (score 5):

Reflection is used extensively in Java by frameworks which are leveraged at runtime to operate with other code *dynamically*.  Without reflection, all links between code must be done at compile time (*statically*).

So, for example, *any* useful plug-in framework (OSGi, JSPF, JPF),  leverages Reflection.  Any injection framework (Spring, Guice, etc) leverages Reflection.

Any time you want to write a piece of code that will interact with another piece of code *without* having that piece of code available when compiling, Reflection is the way forward in Java.

However, this is best left to frameworks and should be encapsulated.

Comment: another way to do it, is using GCLIB and dynamic code generation

Answer (score 1):

Frameworks like Spring or Hibernate make extensive use of reflection to inspect a class and see the annotations.

Comment: @ZachRattner An annotation is a bit of metadata placed in code before various elements like class declarations, methods etc. An annotation doesn't do anything on its own but can be used by tools for various purposes like generating additional artefacts or checking constraints. On the one hand, this is meta-information and you don't want to hard-code the behaviour in your own class. On the other hand, providing such info in separate files takes it away from where it belongs: with the code. Enter annotations, to bridge the gap. Info about code for code.

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks for debugging, serialization, logging, testing...